# Initialize AngularFire2 after login

Tags: angular, angularfire2

Hello I'm using AngularFire2 in my app, but I want to know if there's a way to initialize the module after doing the login.

I need to perform the login first, because I download the Firebase Config with a token provided by the login. That's why I need to initialize the module after login. Could I use a service?

Comment: not sure because I've never tried, but maybe you could nest a sub-app within your main app. And give that second app its own `module.ts`: `imports: [
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(myFetchedConfig),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using a service. As I don't need the firebase configuration details until after login in, I wrote a service and use it as a provider.

So here is my **app.module**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    ...,
    FirebaseInitService
  ]
})
```

And here is my **FirebaseInitService**:

```
import { FirebaseApp } from 'angularfire2/firebase.app.module';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database/';
import firebase from '@firebase/app';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseInitService {
  fb: FirebaseApp;
  db: AngularFireDatabase;

  constructor() {
    // Here is where I load firebase config for initializing it.
    var firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: ...,
      ...
    };
    this.fb = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig) as FirebaseApp;
    this.db = new AngularFireDatabase(this.fb);
  }

  // Connecting to Firebase database through this.db instance
  getData() {
    return this.db.something();
  }
}
```

As it may be notice it need to use both Firebase and FirebaseApp for creating the Firebase instance, and it's very important casting it to FirebaseApp for allowing to instance AngularFireDatabase.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently no good way to initialize the AngularFireModule after launch with different keys.

Comment: I'm currently working on a pull request which would utilize Dependency Injection in the instantiation of the modules, see here https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/pull/1454 (the `FirebaseAppConfig` and `FirebaseAppName` tokens) once that's in it will be much easier. I'll revise the answer once merged.